# VBA script for Random Value Generator in Excel is includes value not in the array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I create an array that the random number generator should pull from. The array is on a sheet and the values from a column are included if the column to their left has a value of 1 (1 means playing, 0 means not playing). Everything seems to be working when I test it with 10 numbers indicating playing and 1000+ numbers indicating not playing EXCEPT FOR 0 being included in the array of numbers when the numbers go from 1-1500. 
Here is the code:

```
Sub RandArray()

Dim RandArray As Variant, cell As Range
ReDim RandArray(0)
For Each cell In Worksheets("Registration").Range("B:B").Cells
    If cell.Value = "1" Then
        RandArray(UBound(RandArray)) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        ReDim Preserve RandArray(UBound(RandArray) + 1)
    End If
Next cell
ReDim Preserve RandArray(UBound(RandArray))
Range("A27").Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(LBound(RandArray), UBound(RandArray))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB6 `[Re]Dim array(N)` define an array with *N+1* elements<sup>1</sup>, 0, 1, ..., N.
`ReDim Preserve RandArray(UBound(RandArray) + 1)` correctly exploit this fact, growing the array by one element.

`ReDim Preserve RandArray(UBound(RandArray))` however is incorrect: let *N*+1 be the number of elements of `RandArray`, then `UBound(RandArray)` is *N*, the last valid index; so `ReDim Preserve RandArray(UBound(RandArray))` is equivalent to `ReDim Preserve RandArray(N)` which still have *N* + 1 elements.

To get rid of the spurious last null element, shrink the array with `ReDim Preserve RandArray(UBound(RandArray)-1)`

---

<sup>1</sup> Assuming no `Option Base 1`.

Comment: Thank you! this worked in combination with the answer above!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random element of RandArray then:

```
Range("A27").Value = RandArray(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(LBound(RandArray), UBound(RandArray)))
```

*(your code just gets a random index)*
I would also use:

```
For Each cell In Intersect(Worksheets("Registration").Range("B:B").Cells,Worksheets("Registration").UsedRange)
```

To speed things up.

Comment: Thank you! this worked in combination with the answer below

Comment: @erikasoladams  Thank you for the feedback! ...................the topic of making random picks is of interest to me.